# Leetcode's two sums error __init__() missing 2 positional arguments

Tags: python, constructor, arguments

I'm solving leetcode's two sums and I get error `__init__() missing 2 positional arguments`

Here is my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self, nums, target):
        self.nums = nums
        self.target = target
    def twoSum(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.nums)):
            j = self.target-self.nums[i]
            for a in range(i+1,len(self.nums)):
                if self.nums[a]==j:
                    return "(%d, %d)" % (self.nums[i], self.nums[a])
```

Comment: You probably should "shift" your parameters to the `twoSum` function, it has not much to do with how you *define* your class, more how it is "used".

Comment: You must be calling `Solution()`, but you should be calling `Solution(nums, target)`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Helpful may be ["how to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Users here are way more ready to help if you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Solution` class is probably missing array and target upon instantiation.

You can make it like so:

```
class Solution(object):

    def __init__(self, nums, target):
        self.nums = nums
        self.target = target

    def twoSum(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.nums)):
            j = self.target-self.nums[i]
            for a in range(i+1,len(self.nums)):
                if self.nums[a]==j:
                    return "(%d, %d)" % (self.nums[i], self.nums[a])

 nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6] # Array of numbers
 target = 7 # Target
 s = Solution(nums, target)
 print(s.twoSum())
```

EDIT:

I runned code in idle. This is what I get for your code:

[image: Idle run]

But I found solution online, and it goes like this:

```
class Solution:
    # @return a tuple, (index1, index2)
    def twoSum(self, num, target):
        length = len(num)
        # use dict: value: index + 1
        # since there is only one solution, the right value must not be duplicated
        dic = {}
        for i in range(0, length):
            val = num[i]
            if (target - val) in dic:
                return (dic[target - val], i + 1)
            dic[val] = i + 1



# test code
num=[2, 7, 11, 15]
t= 26
s = Solution()
print(s.twoSum(num, t))
```

The solution works in LeetCode interface.

Comment: Hi @Dinko Pehar, I did add your part, and Leetcode still displayed the same error.
Line 26: TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'nums' and 'target'

Comment: Hi @Dinko Pehar! Thank you so much for your help. I got so much too learn :))